# Getting error while try to insert new record after deleting

Tags: trigger

```
trigger OpportunityRollUpPayments on Opportunity_Splits__c(after delete, after insert, after update) {

  set<Id> OpportunityIds = new set<Id>();

  if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){
    for(Opportunity_Splits__c p : trigger.new){
      OpportunityIds.add(p.Opportunity__c);
    }
  } 
  if(trigger.isDelete){
    for(Opportunity_Splits__c p : trigger.old){
      OpportunityIds.add(p.Opportunity__c);
    }
  }
  map<Id,Double> OpportunityMap = new map<Id,Double> ();
  for(AggregateResult q : [select Opportunity__c,sum(Percent__c) from Opportunity_Splits__c where Opportunity__c IN :OpportunityIds group by Opportunity__c]){
      OpportunityMap.put((Id)q.get('Opportunity__c'),(Double)q.get('expr0'));
  }
  List<Opportunity> OpportunitiesToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
  for(Opportunity o : [Select Id, Total_Payments__c from Opportunity where Id IN :OpportunityIds]){
    Double PaymentSum = OpportunityMap.get(o.Id);
    o.Total_Payments__c = PaymentSum;
    OpportunitiesToUpdate.add(o);
  }  
  if(OpportunityIds.size()>0)
    for(Opportunity_Splits__c objC : trigger.new)
    {
       if(OpportunityMap .containskey(objC.Opportunity__c))
       {               
        if(OpportunityMap .get(objC.Opportunity__c) > 100)
        {
            objC.addError('Parent Opportunity Sum is greater than 100');
        }                
       }
      update OpportunitiesToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Error:

> Validation Errors While Saving Record(s) There were custom validation
>   error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first
>   validation error encountered was "Apex trigger
>   OpportunityRollUpPayments caused an unexpected exception, contact your
>   administrator: OpportunityRollUpPayments: execution of AfterDelete
>   caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null
>   object: Trigger.OpportunityRollUpPayments: line 26, column 1".

Comment: Hi Shweta, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)
There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Apex trigger OpportunityRollUpPayments caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: OpportunityRollUpPayments: execution of AfterDelete caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.OpportunityRollUpPayments: line 26, column 1".

Comment: @shweta you are getting error in `OpportunityRollUpPayments` trigger and you have posted code of `ContactTrigger `. This will not help.

Comment: please post the correct trigger code.. or both of them. You can edit you question again and include both codes.

Comment: Could you please post error logs from debug logs?

Comment: [24]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.hasNext()
11:03:40.72 (80462877)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[24]|o|null|
11:03:40.72 (80498771)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[30]|Bytes:41
11:03:40.72 (80639111)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Trigger.OpportunityRollUpPayments: line 30, column 1
11:03:40.72 (80645240)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Comment: @TusharSharma i have changed the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
trigger OpportunityRollUpPayments on Opportunity_Splits__c(after delete, after insert, after update) {

  set<Id> OpportunityIds = new set<Id>();
  List<Opportunity_Splits__c> opportunitySplitList = new List<Opportunity_Splits__c>();

    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        for(Opportunity_Splits__c p : trigger.new)
        {
            OpportunityIds.add(p.Opportunity__c);    
            opportunitySplitList.add(p);
        }
    } 

    if(trigger.isDelete)
    {
        for(Opportunity_Splits__c p : trigger.old)
        {
            OpportunityIds.add(p.Opportunity__c);    
            opportunitySplitList.add(p);
        }
    }

    Map<Id,Double> OpportunityMap = new Map<Id,Double> ();
    for(AggregateResult q : [select Opportunity__c,sum(Percent__c) from Opportunity_Splits__c where Opportunity__c IN :OpportunityIds group by Opportunity__c])
    {
      OpportunityMap.put((Id)q.get('Opportunity__c'),(Double)q.get('expr0'));
    }

    List<Opportunity> OpportunitiesToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();

    for(Opportunity o : [Select Id, Total_Payments__c from Opportunity where Id IN :OpportunityIds])
    {
        if(OpportunityMap.get(o.Id) <> null)
        {        
            Double PaymentSum = OpportunityMap.get(o.Id);
            o.Total_Payments__c = PaymentSum;
            OpportunitiesToUpdate.add(o);
        }
    }  

    for(Opportunity_Splits__c objC : opportunitySplitList)
    {
       if(OpportunityMap.containskey(objC.Opportunity__c))
       {               
            if(OpportunityMap.get(objC.Opportunity__c) > 100)
            {
                objC.addError('Parent Opportunity Sum is greater than 100');
            }           
       }
    }

    update OpportunitiesToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: this code work fine according to my requirement ,Thanks ..

Answer (score 1):

```
if(OpportunityIds.size()>0)
    for(Opportunity_Splits__c objC : trigger.new)
    {
```

You are getting error in for loop `Trigger.new` because in case of after delete we don't get value in `Trigger.New`. So you need to put a check for that

```
if(OpportunityIds.size()>0  && !trigger.isDelete)
        for(Opportunity_Splits__c objC : trigger.new)
        {
```

Comment: thanks, this work fine.bt when i am deleting opp split record ,this will not update the Total_Payments__c  on opportunity.

Comment: @shweta you can use `Trigger.old` for that.